# SessionHandler::gc(): ps_files_cleanup_dir | Permission denied (13)

Tags: php, centos, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

i have a problem with PHP7 in CentoOS (WHM/CPANEL) and Prestashop 1.7

the system gives me this messagges:

```
Notice on line 429 in file /home/onywf3fr9a/public_html/app/cache/dev/classes.php
```

[8] SessionHandler::gc(): ps_files_cleanup_dir: opendir(/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php70) failed: Permission denied (13)

Comment: Did you tried to make this directory writable?

Comment: Check your directory permissions in FileZilla

Comment: "ps_files_cleanup_dir" probably means that you should try to allow delete actions within this directory

Answer (score 24):

### Background

This error occurs when PHP tries to garbage collect expired sessions, but the directory containing the session files is not listable (missing the `r` access bit) by the user PHP runs as.

**This is usually a security measure against PHP session hijacking.** E.g. Debian sets the permissions for the session directory to `drwx-wx-wt`. These permissions allow anyone to create sessions and the user who created the session may read it again if they knows the file name (session id), but only root can get a *list* of all active sessions.

Distributions with this configuration normally also set up a cronjob or timer that regularly cleans up the sessions and disable the native garbage collection in php.ini: `session.gc_probability = 0`.

### Possible Causes

1. You or someone else modified the `php.ini` and changed [`session.gc_probability`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability) to a value other than `0`.
2. A PHP script uses [`ini_set()`](https://www.php.net/ini_set) to modify `session.gc_probability` at runtime. Some PHP frameworks are prone to this. E.g. [Symfony always sets `session.gc_probability` to `1` if not configured otherwise](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html#configuring-garbage-collection).
3. You or someone else managing the server botched up the session directory permissions on a system that doesn't use a cronjob or timer to cleanup expired sessions.

### Solutions

1. Change `session.gc_probability` in php.ini to `0` after verifying that your installation uses a cronjob/timer for session cleanup.

   - CPanel uses `/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/clean_user_php_sessions` to remove expired sessions, so all CPanel installations use a cronjob.
   - Debian, Ubuntu and Linux Mint use a systemd timer `phpsessionclean.timer` for session cleanup.
2. Prevent the web application from overriding `session.gc_probability`. For Symfony based applications this can be done by modifying `config/packages/framework.yaml`:

   ```yaml
   framework:
       session:
           gc_probability: null
   ```
3. If your system really uses the native session garbage collection instead of a cronjob or timer, change the permissions of the session folder to allow listing for the user running PHP:

   ```sh
   # Check beforehand which group php-fpm runs as. Here I assume www-data:
   chgrp www-data /var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php70
   chmod g+r /var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php70
   ```

   **Security notice**: Changing the permissions allows **any** PHP script to enumerate all active session ids and potentially access all sessions. Only do this if you are sure the solutions above aren't applicable!
4. *(Potentially dangerous)* Change [`session.save_path`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path) to `/tmp` or a similar directory that PHP can access for reading and writing.

   **Security notice**: Changing the session save path to a world-readable directory allows **any** program and any PHP script to enumerate all active session ids and potentially access all sessions. Only do this if you are sure the solutions above aren't applicable!

Comment: It really helped me with the Symfony explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

I have the same issue, I changed the `session.save_path`[image: php.ini] to "/tmp" in my php.ini

Comment: Are there any security issues with changing the sessions folder to "tmp" instead of the 'var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php73' directory?

Comment: what was the value before you changed to "/tmp"?

Comment: @Kat Yes, there is one issue: /tmp is listable by any user (`rwt`). That means that every program on the server can enumerate all active session ids and every PHP script can list and access all active sessions.

Comment: I think this is a prestashop issue.. If there is an existing GC.. why prestashop try clean this folder. Change the path or did a chmod is not the a good solution for me

Comment: @Pad prestashop uses the Symfony framework and that is known to override the GC settings unconditionally. See solution 2 of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69574150/1941973).

Answer (score 5):

I cleared cache and problem has been solved :)

Comment: I have this same error, changed the path file to /tmp in php.ini and also cleared the cache, yet the same error is showing.

Answer (score 3):

For fixing the

`«Notice: SessionHandler::gc(): ps_files_cleanup_dir: opendir("/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php70") failed: Permission denied"`

I recommend to grant the write access rights for this particular folder (/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php70) to the operating system account you use for the PHP interpreter.

Disabling the PHP's session garbage collector with the session.gc_probability=0 PHP setting is not a good solution, because you will have a lot of orphaned session files in the session folder, and it will waste the disk space and slow down your server.

Comment: "because you will have a lot of orphaned session files in the session folder" --- does not debian php package come with a dedicated cron job that cleans the sessions independently of php?

Comment: @zerkms no, it does not. Php run it's session garbage collectors based on information set in php.init / during script execution. However **you should always have dedicated directories for every project sessions, because their lifetime settings might be different, causing sessions to expire earlier than anticipated if directory is shared**.

Comment: @SteveB well, debian and ubuntu packages come with built-in GC disabled and with an external cleanup scripts that are run via cron or systemd. Just install it and check yourself.

Comment: @zerkms well, you got me. Linking relevant question on servelfault for reference: https://serverfault.com/questions/511609/why-does-debian-clean-php-sessions-with-a-cron-job-instead-of-using-phps-built.

Comment: @Dmitriy Buteiko, when I grant permission as root it works but the next day I get the same exception again !!! what should I do to make it permanent ? I always run these two commandes:1- `sudo chown username: -R /var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php70` ## 2- `sudo chmod u+w -R /var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php70`

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs, because you need folder permission to store your session files in the session folder.

This error is common for all popular frameworks. Solution is
1. Give permission to the session folder as showing to store files OR
2. create a local session folder in your project and rewrite the session files storing path in your project.

Answer (score -1):

While this is not exactly elegant, I have found a solution that works for me at least.  I noticed if I simply wait a second and refresh the page, I get though.  I get this error when I am testing and going back and forth pages quickly.

```
$count = 0;

  do {
    if (@session_start()) {
      break;
    }
    sleep(1);
    $count++;
  } while ($count < 4);
```

While this creates a slight delay, and it doesn't create an infinite loop, it seems to give the server to catch up on things.