# Notice: SessionHandler::gc(): ps_files_cleanup_dir: opendir(/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php70) failed: Permission denied (13)

Tags: php

Can someone please help me please

> Notice: SessionHandler::gc(): ps_files_cleanup_dir:
>   opendir(/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php70) failed: Permission denied
>   (13)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47043351/sessionhandlergc-ps-files-cleanup-dir-permission-denied-13

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SessionHandler::gc(): ps\_files\_cleanup\_dir | Permission denied (13)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47043351/sessionhandlergc-ps-files-cleanup-dir-permission-denied-13)