# PHP Session Storage / Update Issue

Tags: php, session, permissions, session-cookies

Before getting marked for duplicate questions, I know about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585086/how-can-i-fix-the-permission-error-when-i-call-session-start) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821532/php-warning-permission-denied-13-on-session-start) issues.

My problem WAS the same: I have a chat polling script, that fires a request to the server every xth second, and after n requests without update content coming from the server, the interval time is extended by x. As soon as a response holding update content is returned by the server, the interval time is reset to x.

EXCLUSIVELY for this script, after what seems to be a random amount of `m` polling requests, the request fails, and I get a `500` internal server error, saying:

```
PHP Notice:  session_start() [function.session-start.php]: ps_files_cleanup_dir: opendir(/var/cache/php-sessions) failed: Permission denied (13)
```

I then, according to the provided questions and other forums, created a `php-sessions` folder within my server root, with an access of `700`, and set the `session_save_path` to the according directory. The sessions now get effectively stored within that directory.

BUT, I now do not get the above-mentioned error anymore, but instead a `400` client error, also after a random amount `m` of polling requests, with the server replying with `0`.

My hosting service tells me to look for help in PHP forums, but in my opinion this does not make any sense, as the request does not even reach the server, and hence what's the link to PHP here?

I just wanted to check if anyone had the same issue, and how to tackle this?

***UPDATE***

Not sure if this helps, but I've checked back with my host, and they've said the following:

- They have a cronjob which deletes sessions which are older than 24 hours from the `/var/cache/php-sessions` folder.
- They additionally use php's native garbage collector with `session.gc_probability = 1`

Can it may be that these two somehow compete with each other, and that that causes the error?

Comment: (1) In my experience, there is no need to change the duration between queries to the server (every xth seconds) (2) Normally 5 seconds is already ok for normal chatting for all clients (3) Normally a server can handle many clients visiting the same db to query the latest chatting data if each user visits it only once in 5 seconds --- unless your hosting plan has traffic limit imposed. (4) to minimize traffic to/from the server, query should only get the latest chat if there is CHANGE in the chatting data, so first get the no. of records, if there is no change, don't get further chat records

Comment: I think you need to give access to apache to write into `/var/lib/php/session`

Comment: @KenLee (4) is pretty much how I do it, yup, and totally agree with (1) - (3). The traffic limit thing can't be the reason though, as the site hasn't even been deployed yet, and the mentioned errors occur with a single user being logged in, hence a single user polling.

Comment: @executable but the problem does not seem to be access-related, the directory I've setup has all the access rights you need. And well, I guess I can't even do what you're saying, as the /var directory is within a directory I do not have access to (shared host). But just in theory, maybe I need to explicitly allow the access to apache, even to the created `php-sessions` folder? How do I do that?

Comment: _"as the request does not even reach the server"_ - who said it didn't? Are you confused by the 400 status code? That is still a _server response_, even if it says "client error" (it simply means that the error was _caused_ rather by how the client was behaving, than anything going wrong on the server side.)

Comment: The function name mentioned in the message suggests that this happens during garbage collection, so check if the information from https://stackoverflow.com/q/47043351/1427878 is any help.

Comment: @CBroe yes 'didn't reach the server' was the wrong wording, but you get what I mean. Okay hmm I'll have a look at your link, but my error message does not explicitly mention the garbage collector..?

Comment: The mentioned procedure name `ps_files_cleanup_dir` is a pretty good hint that this is garbage collection-related.

Comment: .... And your link actually showed that what I did can be extremely dangerous as I'm making all of my sessions available to basically any server-side program? Damn

Comment: Is that the case or don't you see a security risk using my approach with the 'php-sessions' folder? Because I think my issue of the 400 error could be related to the fact that my access rights of that folder are `700` so nothing like `drwx-wx-wt` as your link mentions. And also, there's no garbage collection implemented. Your link (as I understand it) simply tells to entirely disable garbage collection for the sessions, doesn't that mean that the session files will endlessly accumulate??

Comment: So before disabling the native session garbage collection, I must assure that my hosting service implements some kind of scheduled custom garbage collection, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came around a variety of different issues when trying to combine PHP's native `$_SESSION`s with some of my project setups. The main issue was my attempt to try to combine PHP Sessions (stateful) with stateless approaches like `REST`. I finally concluded that in such cases, it's better to implement your own session handling using performant DB solutions like [redis](https://redis.com/blog/json-web-tokens-jwt-are-dangerous-for-user-sessions/), or simply setup your own logic by [adapting PHP's native session handling](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.session-set-save-handler.php).